# Error: I can't download files larger than 70KB to my Google Cloud Storage bucket

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-storage, bun

I'm having an issue with GCS and Bun. It turns out that I want to download an image from my bucket, and I'm encountering an error. I'm using the `.download()` method from the GCS library, but it gives me an error for files larger than a certain size in KB.

This worked fine in Express, but when doing it in Bun, it doesn't, and I don't know why. What I'm trying to do is pass an array of public URLs that I have in my bucket, download them, and send them by email. However, for files larger than approximately 70KB, it doesn't work because the code stops, and nothing gets sent. I'm getting the following errors:

```
262 | 'ECONNREFUSED',
263 | ].includes(err.code))) {
264 | let code = 'UNKNOWN';
265 | if (err.code)
266 | code = err.code;
267 | process.emitWarning(`received unexpected error = ${err.message} code = ${code}`, 'MetadataLookupWarning');
^
warn: received unexpected error = Was there a typo in the URL or port? code = FailedToOpenSocket
at /mnt/c/Users/user/Desktop/proyect/node_modules/gcp-metadata/build/src/index.js:267:16
at processTicksAndRejections (:61:76)

11 | // Since node 6.3.0 state.buffer is a BufferList not an array
12 | if (state.buffer.head) {
13 | return state.buffer.head.data.length
14 | }
15 |
16 | return state.buffer[0].length
               ^
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'state.buffer[0].length')
at getStateLength (/mnt/c/Users/user/Desktop/proyect/node_modules/stream-shift/index.js:16:11)
at shift (/mnt/c/Users/user/Desktop/proyect/node_modules/stream-shift/index.js:6:98)
at /mnt/c/Users/user/Desktop/proyect/node_modules/duplexify/index.js:170:34
at onreadable (/mnt/c/Users/user/Desktop/proyect/node_modules/duplexify/index.js:136:4)
at processTicksAndRejections (:61:76)
```

I'm not sure what these errors refer to. I've tried updating the library, dependencies, etc., but nothing seems to work. The error seems to have occurred when I switched from Express to Bun because it used to work perfectly fine before.

**EDIT**: This is the line, with files larger than approximately 70KB, it doesn't go beyond this line, meaning it doesn't download them:
`const downloadResponse = await findFile.download();`

Comment: It looks like this issue is tracked in GitHub for the GCS Node library here: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues/2368